# Is querying with NOT IN faster then querying with IN?

Tags: mysql, performance

Let's presume the following simple situation:

I have two tables, a **category** table that contains two fields, `CategoryId`, and `CategoryGroup`, and an **ads** table that contains another two fields, `AdId`, and `category_CategoryId` which is a link to the **category** table.

All the rows in the **category** table are grouped in two separate groups: *buy* or *rent*. So, each row in that table has in the `CategoryGroup` either the string *buy* or the string *rent*.

Let's say I want to count how many ads I have in the **ads** which are for sale.

I have two ways to do this:

1. Do a `NOT IN` query like this: `SELECT COUNT(AdId) as Total FROM ads WHERE category_CategoryId NOT IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM category WHERE CategoryGroup = 'rent')`
2. Or do an 'IN' query like this: `SELECT COUNT(AdId) as Total FROM ads WHERE category_CategoryId IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM category WHERE CategoryGroup = 'buy')`

I've tested both queries, and it seems to me, that the `NOT IN` query performs way faster than the `IN` type of query.

(0.45 secs for `NOT IN` on a table of ~900.000 rows, and with around 45 categories, while 1.1 secs for `IN` on the same dataset)

Is this incidental, or `NOT IN` queries will always perform faster in simmilar situations?

Comment: It is better to do LEFT JOIN and filter with IS [NOT] NULL for columns of subtable.

Comment: Do you have an approximately equal number of categories with a CategoryGroup of 'rent' versus 'buy'? That is another variable to consider, as the IN and NOT IN are querying against those two different sets.

Comment: The proportion is 19 to 26 on the two groups.

Comment: @i486: you mean like this? `SELECT Count(ads.AdId) as Total, ads.category_CategoryId  FROM ads LEFT JOIN category ON category.CategoryId = ads.category_CategoryId WHERE category.CategoryGroup = 'buy' GROUP BY ads.category_CategoryId`

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Yes, something like this.

Comment: @i486 - Almost; get rid of the `LEFT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` and `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` are perhaps *never* the most efficient way to code something.  One may be faster than the other because `SELECT` has fewer rows than the other, not because of `NOT`.

Assuming an ad is in only one category, this is probably the most efficient.

```
SELECT  Count(ads.AdId) as Total, ads.CategoryId
    FROM  ads
    JOIN  category AS c ON c.CategoryId = ads.CategoryId
    WHERE  c.CategoryGroup = 'buy'
    GROUP BY  ads.CategoryId
```

If an ad can be in multiple categories, then you have a puzzle:  Should an ad that is both 'buy' and 'rent' be included or excluded from the count?  Anyway, I am leading up to replacing `IN` with `EXISTS` as an alternative optimization:

```
SELECT  Count(AdId) as Total, CategoryId
    FROM  ads
    WHERE  EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  category
            WHERE  CategoryId = ads.CategoryId
              AND  CategoryGroup = 'buy' 
      )
    GROUP BY  CategoryId
```

(Sorry, I can't stand unnecessarily redundant column names like `category_CategoryId`.)

Perform `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on the various choices to get more insight.

Comment: This really seems faster:) (P.s: I use the redundant column names, so I will always know which table a column points to, it makes it easier for me, but that's just me:D)

Comment: two things. You probably want a composite index for `(CategoryId,CategoryGroup)` also dont use `SELECT *` for `EXISTS` dbEngine will  have to do a lookup to the table again to find the * fields after find row with the index, total waste. Just use `SELECT 1`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) -- "Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference. "

Comment: My first query would like the "covering" index of `(CategoryGroup, CategoryId)`, specifically in that order.  My second can benefit from that index, but the opposite order is equally good.